# How to convert Time to Long?

Tags: java, android, time

For ex., I have the following value:

```
Time.valueOf("2:00:00")
```

how should I convert it to `Long`? (to be stored in SQLite database as `Real`)

`java.sql.Time` is used.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [getTime()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29):

```
Time t = Time.valueOf("2:00:00");
long l = t.getTime();
```

Comment: It shows the wrong long value i mean it returns wrong timestamp value.
Time t = Time.valueOf("05:50:00"); l = t.getTime(); but i get l as 1200000 this is not timestamp for that